# Grails: custom constraint error messages

Tags: grails, dns

I have class like this

```
class Account{

   AccType type ;

   static constraints ={
      type(nullable:false);
   }
}
```

and in grails/i18n/message.properties I wrote:

> account.type.null = Please filled in with account type

but it seems the error still : 
Property [type] of class [class Account] cannot be null

How to change the error messages with my own message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

`account.type.nullable=Nice message....`.

See [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/nullable.html).